# Gitlab CI: Fetch artifacts from upstream merge request pipeline, error "This job could not start because..."

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

According to Gitlab [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Multi-project%20pipeline#fetch-artifacts-from-an-upstream-merge-request-pipeline), I try to download artifacts from upstream merge request pipeline to downstream pipeline. And it is for multi-pipeline projects.

With this example code, downstream pipeline is triggered successfully, but it failed immediately with below error.

We have Gitlab premium, btw. Please advice what am I missing?

#### upstream jobs

```
build_artifacts:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "This is a test artifact!" >> artifact.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifact.txt

upstream_job:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  variables:
    UPSTREAM_REF: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_REF_PATH
  trigger:
    project: my/downstream_project
    branch: my-branch
```

#### downstream job

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cat artifact.txt
  needs:
    - project: my/upstream_project
      job: build_artifacts
      ref: $UPSTREAM_REF
      artifacts: true
```

`This job could not start because it could not retrieve the needed artifacts.`